# BIND having trouble resolving service.graphicly.com

Tags: linux, fedora, bind, resolve

Since about two weeks ago, we haven't been able to resolve service.graphicly.com:

```
dig @192.168.0.12 service.graphicly.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.4-P1 <<>> @192.168.0.12 service.graphicly.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Digging on the name servers listed for graphicly.com shows that service.graphicly.com is a CNAME to takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net. Digging on cloudapp.net's name servers seems to fail:

```
dig @NS1.LIVEDNS.MSFT.NET takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net

; <<>> DiG 9.3.4-P1 <<>> @NS1.LIVEDNS.MSFT.NET takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Somehow, my home ISP's name servers can resolve service.graphicly.com without issue. Has anyone else noticed this problem? Does anyone know what the cause of this problem could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I run some DNS servers that are sometimes blocked by other DNS servers. By far the easiest way around this is to add some explicit forwarders (like Google, Verizon or OpenDNS) for those zones.

Add the following to named.conf:

```
zone "graphicly.com" { type forward; forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; 4.2.2.2; 4.2.2.1; }; };
zone "cloudapp.net"  { type forward; forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; 4.2.2.2; 4.2.2.1; }; };
```

Do this for any zone that is blocking your DNS server's requests.

Answer (score 0):

the response I get is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2.1 <<>> service.graphicly.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40966
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;service.graphicly.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.graphicly.com.  3600    IN      CNAME   takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net.
takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net. 10 IN     A       70.37.95.218

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cloudapp.net.           172800  IN      NS      ns2.livedns.msft.net.
cloudapp.net.           172800  IN      NS      ns1.livedns.msft.net.

;; Query time: 373 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 19 15:26:21 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 146
```

Is bind configured to do recursive root DNS lookups itself, or to forward requests to another server? (like your ISPs)

my bind options stanza featues **no** forwarders section, and has "recursion yes;" to ensure it does lookups itself instead of delegating to another DNS server

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yep, we allow recursion from within our subnet, and have no forwarders.

Comment: My stanza looks as follows: allow-recursion { 192.168.0.0/24; localhost; 10.8.0.0/24; };

Answer (score 0):

They both work fine for me. Might try adding Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8) as secondary or tertiary DNS in your system.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.2-P1-RedHat-9.6.2-2.P1.fc12 <<>> service.graphicly.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45402
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;service.graphicly.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.graphicly.com.  3600    IN      CNAME   takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net.
takecomicsadmin.cloudapp.net. 10 IN     A       70.37.95.218

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       4524    IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       4524    IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 330 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(10.227.1.20)
;; WHEN: Wed May 19 10:37:56 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 305
```